# Rails 3.0.9 in ruby 1.9.3 render partials performance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, render, partial

I have the following hierarchy of partials rendering which results in a table

- render: partial => table

  - render: partial => row,: collection => rows
  - ---- render: partial => cell,: collection => row.cells
  - -------render: partial => "# {cell.partial}",: locals => {: item => cell.item}

In prodakshion renedering 5000 rows takes 12 seconds

At the same PC - "Web interface Oracle" draws the same 5000 lines in 2 seconds.
That is 6 times faster.

What's the problem? How can i optimize rails performace ?

We are using the slim, but with haml it's the same
Working on windows...

Moving partials to helper methods gives me 3x speed!

Comment: To optimize anything it helps to know what is slow and starting there, have you profiled the code?

Comment: i've got a problem with profiling cause i am using windows as development platform. But all partials are like == item.text

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here is the problem:
small partials are not efficient. Use helpers instead.

When I changed "render small partial" to  "call helper method" 
I got 5x rendering performance.

Sad but true